# What is the correlation between scores on Verbal and Culture Fair tests for Cattell III Scales?

Tags: iq

Adults looking to join Mensa in Britain via sitting an entrance test offered by the organization, are able to sit two separately scored IQ test papers:

1. Cattell III A ,  mean = 100 , SD = 16
2. Cattell III B ,  mean = 100 , SD = 24

Candidates can sit both papers and are eligible for signing up if they score at least 2 standard deviations above the mean on at least one of the papers.

The first paper is a visually based test (diagrammatic reasoning), whereas the second is a mostly verbal reasoning orientated test.

This allows candidates to receive 2 different IQ scores.

Whilst both scores could be easily calibrated to a standard deviation of 15 (perhaps with some rounding required), I have never come across the numerical correlation between scores for the different Cattell III scales (nor what distribution a combination of the scores would have) and therefore do not know how to combine the results into an overall IQ score, even if normal distributions are assumed throughout.

Are there any (legally) available data on the correlation between scores for adults for the two Cattell III scales, or at least a rough formula for combining the scores into an overall one? Or would it be meaningless to do so given the different respective natures of the two Cattell III tests?

Many Thanks.